# Angular 5 Error:Can't bind to 'ngForFor' since it isn't a known property of 'li'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My category.component.ts is 
[category.component.ts](https://i.hizliresim.com/2a0gYA.png)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { Category } from './category';
@Component({
selector: 'app-category',
templateUrl: './category.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./category.component.css'],
providers: [CategoryService]
})
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'Category';
categories: Category[];
constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {}
ngOnInit() {
this.getCategories();
}
getCategories() {
this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(res => {
  this.categories = res;
});
}
}
```

My category.component.html is
[category.component.html](https://i.hizliresim.com/8zygk7.png)

```
<h3>{{title}}</h3>
<ul>
<li *ngFor='let item2 for categories'>
  {{item2.CategoryName}}
</li>
</ul>
```

My category.service.ts is 
[category.service.ts](https://i.hizliresim.com/LDqapo.png)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Category } from './category';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
 return this.http.get<Category[]> 
 ('http://northwindapi.azurewebsites.net/api/categories');
 }
  }
```

The problem is Angular does't accept li with ngFor. How can i solve this?

Comment: Please paste your code inside your question: 1) I don't have the rights to see your png files, 403 forbidden. 2) Not many people are going to retype all the code in a picture just to be able to test it.

Comment: You need to import **`CommonModule`**  in your module which declares category component.

Comment: @Faisal if the hint given in comment is not a reason for error then no comment or clarify your reason for comment in more clear way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change `for` to `of` in the expression

```
<li *ngFor='let item2 of categories'>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Thanks for everything dude :)